# How to stop forward deleting of letters on word programme using a laptop, not applec

Tags: windows-8

I want to stop my computer from deleting the letters ahead of my writing. How can I do that? I must have clicked on something, unwittingly, that started this annoying thing. How to stop it.

Comment: You also seem to have the caps lock on. 1st, press the caps lock key, then the one that says Insert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Word Processor such as Word for instance and have hit the "Insert" key to engage the overwrite function, you can press that "Insert" key again and put in back into normal insert mode.  This should stop the letters from being overwritten in your documents.